# Can I force VS2022 to show numbers instead of Hex values wherever possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio shows me hex numbers in various places, for example here:

[image]

When I click it to copy it, it offers me "Copy", "Copy value", "Copy expression" and "Copy Hexadecimal".

With each option, I end up getting the hex value.
However, I would need the number.

Is there any way to do that easily?

Comment: It is the way the debugger formats an `IntPtr`.  Very sensible choice.  Format overrides have no effect so you'll have to make do with sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it.
There should be a hexadecimal entry, that you can uncheck.